# Finding the sup and inf of the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the $\underline{s}=\lim\inf s_n$ and  $\overline{s}=\lim\sup s_n$ where $s_n=r^{2n}/(1+r^n)$.

$a)$ If $r=1:\overline{s}=\underline{s}=1/2$

$b)$ If $|r|<1:\overline{s}=\underline{s}=0$

$c)$ If $r>1:\overline{s}=\infty,\quad\underline{s}=1/2$

$d)$ If $r<-1:\overline{s}=\infty,\quad\underline{s}=-\infty$

However, apparently the solution for $(c)$ is $\,\overline{s}=\underline{s}=\infty$, but I do not understand why.

---

Another example is for $s_n=n^2-n$ which I stated that $\overline{s}=\infty,\quad\underline{s}=0$, but again the book states that $\,\overline{s}=\underline{s}=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $r>1$, then
$$
\frac{r^{2n}}{1+r^n}=\frac{r^{n}}{1+r^{-n}}\to \infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$. In particular every subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ is such that $s_{n_k}\to \infty$. So the infimum of the set of subsequential limits (which is $\lim\inf s_n$) and supremum of the set of subsequential limits(which is $\lim\sup s_n$)  are both equal to infinity.